# Proving equivalence of statements

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to solve the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_n \eta_n$ converges for every sequence $\xi_n\in l^1$ iff sequence $\eta_n$ is bounded.

If sequence $\eta_n$ is bounded, then exists constant M for which is $|\xi_n|\leq M$, for all $n\geq 1$. Then,
$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_n \eta_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\xi_n| |\eta_n|\leq M \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\xi_n|$ which is finite, since $\xi_n\in l^1$.

But I'm having trouble to prove other implication. I was thinking to define functionals $\Lambda_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\xi_j\eta_j$, $n\geq 1$ and $\Lambda(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_n \eta_n$. Then, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n(x)=\Lambda(x)$.

I don't know if it is possible to conclude from here that $\eta_n$ is bounded or I should prove this implication in some other way?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outline of a "brute force" method goes as follows: If $\{\eta_n\}$ is unbounded, we will find a sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ in $\ell^1$ such that $\sum \xi_n \eta_n$ diverges. If $\{\eta_n\}$ is unbounded from above, then we can find a subsequence $\{\eta_{n_k}\}$ with the property that for each $k \in \Bbb{N}$, $k \leq \eta_{n_k}$. In this case, define $\{\xi_n\}$ as 
$$
\xi_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k^2} & n = n_k \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In this case $\sum_n \xi_n \eta_n = \sum_k \xi_{n_k} \eta_{n_k}$, which you can easily show diverges to $+\infty$.

In the case that $\{\eta_n\}$ is not unbounded from above, but is unbounded from below, use the last argument with the sequence $\{-\eta_n\}$.

Hope this helps.